# Play video URL links stored in database MVC

Tags: c#, html, mysql, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

Hi I'm currently developing a web Application In MVC3. I have created a database called PlayLink and have integrated a media player lean-back www.leanbackplayer.com into a view.

From my view the user can add a URL link to the database and the link appears in the main View. I now need to link the player to the url's stored the database so that when the url is clicked the associated url media file will play in the player.

This is my code for Lean Back player it currently only plays the URL the is pre coded.

```
  <div class="leanback-player-video">
 <video width="500" height="250" preload="auto" controls    p oster="http://dl.dropbox.com/u/46705018/sintel.mp4.mp4">
     <source src="http://dl.dropbox.com/u/46705018/sintel.mp4.mp4" type='video/mp4; codecs="avc1.42E01E, mp4a.40.2"' />

    <object class="leanback-player-flash-fallback" width="500" height="250" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" data="http://player.longtailvideo.com/player.swf">
        <param name="movie" value="http://player.longtailvideo.com/player.swf" />
        <param name="allowFullScreen" value="true" />
        <param name="wmode" value="opaque" />
        <param name="bgcolor" value="#000000" />
        <param name="flashVars" value="controlbar=over&amp;file=http://dl.dropbox.com/u/46705018/sintel.mp4.mp4
                &amp;image=http://dl.dropbox.com/u/46705018/sintel.mp4.mp4" />
    </object>

    <div class="leanback-player-html-fallback" style="width: 500px; height: 250px;">
        <img src="http://dl.dropbox.com/u/46705018/sintel.mp4.mp4" width="500" height="250" alt="Poster Image" 
            title="No HTML5-Video playback capabilities found. Please download the video(s) below." />
        <div>
            <strong>Download Video:</strong>
            <a href="http://dl.dropbox.com/u/46705018/sintel.mp4.mp4">.mp4</a>
        </div>
    </div>
  </video>
</div>
```

MVC Model structure:

```
    using System;
 using System.Data.Entity;
 using System.Collections.Generic;
 using System.Linq;
 using System.Web;

 namespace ProjectNCI.Models
  {
    public class PlayLink
   {
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }

   }
   public class PlayLinkDBContext : DbContext
   {
       public DbSet<PlayLink> PlayLink { get; set; }
   }
}
```

Comment: My first thought is to use ajax and just reload the div with the player src set to the link.